# New to R and trying to filter through rows of data in a dataframe on a condition, but its got some issues

Tags: r

Tried many methods but settled on filter() since it matches what I tried to get done. Problem is i cant get around the console giving me an error saying "must be a logical vector, not the string "*". The idea here is to filter data and I am specifically removing stars( *) and hashtags #.

```
data <- read_excel("E:/editing v2/AverageIncome.xlsx")

filtered_data <- data %>%
  filter('*', '#')

filtered_data
```

Data:

```
structure(list(Area = c("02", "05", "12", "16", "24", "27"), 
    State = c("AK", "AR", "FL", "ID", "MD", "MN"), StateName = c("Alaska", 
    "Arkansas", "Florida", "Idaho", "Maryland", "Minnesota"), 
    JobCode = c("29-1061", "29-1023", "29-1023", "29-1066", "29-1022", 
    "29-1023"), JobName = c("Anesthesiologists", "Orthodontists", 
    "Orthodontists", "Psychiatrists", "Oral and maxillofacial surgeons", 
    "Orthodontists"), Group = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), TotalEmployment = c("**", "**", "**", "**", "**", "**"
    ), Emp_Prse = c("**", "**", "**", "**", "**", "**"), H_Mean = c("#", 
    "#", "#", "#", "#", "#"), A_Mean = c("#", "#", "#", "#", 
    "#", "#"), Mean_Prse = c("*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*"), H_Pct10 = c("#", 
    "#", "#", "#", "#", "#"), H_Pct25 = c("#", "#", "#", "#", 
    "#", "#"), H_Median = c("#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#"), H_Pct75 = c("#", 
    "#", "#", "#", "#", "#"), H_Pct90 = c("#", "#", "#", "#", 
    "#", "#"), A_Pct10 = c("#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#"), A_Pct25 = c("#", 
    "#", "#", "#", "#", "#"), A_Median = c("#", "#", "#", "#", 
    "#", "#"), A_Pct75 = c("#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#"), A_Pct90 = c("#", 
    "#", "#", "#", "#", "#"), AverageYearlySalary = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), AverageHourlySalary = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), ...24 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...25 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), ...26 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...27 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...28 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...29 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...30 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please share your data by including the output of `dput(data)` in a code chunk in your question.

Comment: Try taking a look at `?filter`.

Comment: @Till sorry im a bit new but does that mean you wanted to see the output from the console?

Comment: Yes. The output of `dput(data)` will allow us to transfer your data into an R session an prepare an answer that is tailored to your data.

Comment: I couldnt find an option in the edit section to import files so heres a github link to it instead. let me know if it works or if it needs to be done a bit differently  https://github.com/superchicken11/overflow-data-file/tree/main

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Filter on one column. Drop all rows that have value of "**" for 
# `TotalEmployment`
data |>
  filter(TotalEmployment != "**")
#> # A tibble: 35,251 × 30
#>    Area  State StateName   JobCode JobName Group TotalEmployment Emp_Prse H_Mean
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr>       <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr>           <chr>    <chr> 
#>  1 26    MI    Michigan    29-1023 Orthod… <NA>  100             28.6     #     
#>  2 04    AZ    Arizona     25-1054 Physic… <NA>  100             15.6     *     
#>  3 04    AZ    Arizona     25-1192 Home e… <NA>  100             12.0     *     
#>  4 04    AZ    Arizona     19-2012 Physic… <NA>  100             31.0     *     
#>  5 10    DE    Delaware    27-2023 Umpire… <NA>  100             19.3     *     
#>  6 11    DC    District o… 25-1193 Recrea… <NA>  100             2.6      *     
#>  7 11    DC    District o… 25-1061 Anthro… <NA>  100             5.2      *     
#>  8 12    FL    Florida     25-1053 Enviro… <NA>  100             8.5      *     
#>  9 12    FL    Florida     25-1191 Gradua… <NA>  100             15.0     *     
#> 10 16    ID    Idaho       39-3021 Motion… <NA>  100             23.8     *     
#> # ℹ 35,241 more rows
#> # ℹ 21 more variables: A_Mean <chr>, Mean_Prse <chr>, H_Pct10 <chr>,
#> #   H_Pct25 <chr>, H_Median <chr>, H_Pct75 <chr>, H_Pct90 <chr>, A_Pct10 <chr>,
#> #   A_Pct25 <chr>, A_Median <chr>, A_Pct75 <chr>, A_Pct90 <chr>,
#> #   AverageYearlySalary <chr>, AverageHourlySalary <chr>, ...24 <lgl>,
#> #   ...25 <lgl>, ...26 <lgl>, ...27 <lgl>, ...28 <lgl>, ...29 <lgl>,
#> #   ...30 <lgl>

# Filter range of columns. Drop all rows that have "**", "*", or "#" in any 
# column from `TotalEmployment` to `A_Pct90`
data |>
  filter(!if_any(TotalEmployment:A_Pct90, \(x) x %in% c("**", "*", "#")))
#> # A tibble: 30,927 × 30
#>    Area  State StateName   JobCode JobName Group TotalEmployment Emp_Prse H_Mean
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr>       <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr>           <chr>    <chr> 
#>  1 20    KS    Kansas      41-2012 Gaming… <NA>  100             31.2     10.13 
#>  2 35    NM    New Mexico  37-3012 Pestic… <NA>  100             40.7     10.21 
#>  3 55    WI    Wisconsin   39-3019 Gaming… <NA>  100             36.5     10.29 
#>  4 78    VI    Virgin Isl… 43-2011 Switch… <NA>  100             4.0      10.31 
#>  5 56    WY    Wyoming     47-3016 Helper… <NA>  100             18.6     10.39 
#>  6 40    OK    Oklahoma    51-9193 Coolin… <NA>  100             16.4     10.48 
#>  7 78    VI    Virgin Isl… 21-1093 Social… <NA>  100             15.1     10.66 
#>  8 56    WY    Wyoming     13-2082 Tax pr… <NA>  100             48.0     10.73 
#>  9 20    KS    Kansas      51-4052 Pourer… <NA>  100             29.8     10.78 
#> 10 16    ID    Idaho       51-4035 Millin… <NA>  100             16.4     11.02 
#> # ℹ 30,917 more rows
#> # ℹ 21 more variables: A_Mean <chr>, Mean_Prse <chr>, H_Pct10 <chr>,
#> #   H_Pct25 <chr>, H_Median <chr>, H_Pct75 <chr>, H_Pct90 <chr>, A_Pct10 <chr>,
#> #   A_Pct25 <chr>, A_Median <chr>, A_Pct75 <chr>, A_Pct90 <chr>,
#> #   AverageYearlySalary <chr>, AverageHourlySalary <chr>, ...24 <lgl>,
#> #   ...25 <lgl>, ...26 <lgl>, ...27 <lgl>, ...28 <lgl>, ...29 <lgl>,
#> #   ...30 <lgl>
```

Comment: wow i didnt consider setting a range for the first column to the last. if possible can you explain your thought process on the code and what you did differently than mine so i can try to understand and learn from my mistake?

Comment: The usual way to use`dplyr::filter()` is to specify a condition regarding the values in one column. With helper functions like `if_all()` and `if_any()` you can target one condition at several columns at once. To learn more read the [`filter()` section in Introduction to dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/dplyr.html#filter-rows-with-filter) and the [`filter()` documentation page](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html).